# Upgrading from 1.9 to 2 - What about the SOAP API?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, soap

we're thinking of moving from 1.9 to magento 2 in the future. I'd like to estimate the mass of work necessary for the upgrade. I cannot though find any information on how much the SOAP API was changed? Do we need to rewrite everything that uses the API in 1.9 (product sync, order import etc)? 
And are there significant changes in the data structures:

- API operations (names, parameters?) have changed i guess
- Objects and fields changed?
- Object relations changed?

If you have any hint where to look, would be greatly appreciated. Otherwise i would need to examine each API operation we're using, if its still (remotely) compatible. 
(at the moment we're using the SOAP API v2 in Magento 1.9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire API has changed in Magento 2. No integration code for 1.x will directly translate, though most of the high-level techniques should be largely the same.

You can find the official SOAP documentation here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/soap/bk-soap.html

You may be interested to know Magento 2 has placed a much greater emphasis on the REST API. The API interfaces and functionality should be all but identical for REST vs. SOAP, but the REST documentation is far more extensive, and probably has a lower barrier to entry. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/rest/bk-rest.html

To your direct questions:

- Yes, API operations (names and parameters) have all changed.
- Objects and fields should be *mostly* unchanged, at least equivalent.
- Object relations have not changed.